# PyQt4 Getting the name of QTableWidget that user last clicked from multiple QTableWidgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have 10 `QTablewidgets`. Each of the `QTableWidget` display different data. I want to get the name of the table widget that the last time user clicked ( on any of the cells).

Currently i tried putting all the tables in a list:

```
table1 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
table2 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
...
...
mytablelist = [table1,table2,....]
```

Using `Signal and Slots` I tried this:

```
for item in mytablelist:
    self.connect(item,QtCore.SIGNAL("cellClicked()"),self.Identify)
```

My `Identify` function is as below:

```
def Identify(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    print sender
```

As far as i understand, the `sender()` method should tell me which `Qobject` the signal is coming from.

I don't seems to get any output from `Identify` function. What is causing the problem and how do i fix it?

Is there any better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the problem. It was the problem with the signal `cellClicked()` i used (i have no idea why).

So, I tried to use `itemSelectionChanged()` signal instead of `cellClicked()` i used in my question. It works fine now. After that i just used `index()` method to get the position of table in the tablelist.

```
tableindex = mytablelist.index(sender)
```